# Sort array of strings by 3rd-to-last character based on another array then sort on whole strings

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like:

```
$unsorted = Array(
"0" =>"3470U11",
"1" =>"3470E11",
"2" =>"3470S13",
"3" =>"3470G11",
"4" =>"3470S12",
"5" =>"3470S11",
"6" =>"3470E12",
"7" =>"3470U12",
"8" =>"3470G13",
"9" =>"3470G12",
"10" =>"3470E13",
"11" =>"3470U13"
);
```

And a priority array like this:

```
$sortBy = array('G','D','S','U','E','T','A','L');
```

I need to sort the array by the `substr($value,-3,1)` in the order listed in `$sortBy` so the result becomes like:

```
$sorted = Array(
"0" => "3470G11",
"1" => "3470G12",
"2" => "3470G13",
"3" => "3470S11",
"4" => "3470S12",
"5" => "3470S13",
"6" => "3470U11",
"7" => "3470U12",
"8" => "3470U13",
"9" => "3470E11",
"10" =>"3470E12",
"11" =>"3470E13"
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**usort**

(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
usort — Sort an array by values using a user-defined comparison function

```
$unsorted = Array(
"0" =>"3470U11",
"1" =>"3470E11",
"2" =>"3470S13",
"3" =>"3470G11",
"4" =>"3470S12",
"5" =>"3470S11",
"6" =>"3470E12",
"7" =>"3470U12",
"8" =>"3470G13",
"9" =>"3470G12",
"10" => "s3470E13",
"11" => "s3470U13"
);

//$a and $b -> two elts of the array
function cmp ($a,$b){

    $substring_a = substr($a, -3,1);
    $substring_b = substr($b, -3,1);
    
    $sortArr = array('G','D','S','U','E','T','A','L');
    
    $key_a = array_search($substring_a, $sortArr);
    $key_b = array_search($substring_b, $sortArr);
    
    if($key_a == $key_b){
        return strcmp(substr($a, -2),substr($b, -2));
        
    }   
    return $key_a > $key_b;

}

usort($unsorted, "cmp");
print_r($unsorted);
```

Comment: Calling `array_search()` twice on each iteration is not efficient or best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a user defined compare function when sorting.
[usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) if you want the indexes to be rearanged or
[uasort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) if you want to keep the keys as they are.

Your callback function can be something like this:

```
public function sortCallback($item1, $item2){
     $orderArr = array('G','D','S','U','E','T','A','L');

     $iItem1 = array_search( substr($item1,-3,1), $orderArr );
     $iItem2 = array_search( substr($item2,-3,1), $orderArr );

     if($iItem1 == $iItem2){
          return 0;
     }

     return ($iItem1 < $iItem2) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

See on php.net:

- [usort();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)
- [uasort();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)
- [array_search();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Comment: why the downvote? if you downvote, please leave a comment

Comment: Yes i am agree too

Comment: I did not DV, but this answer is very inefficient because it is  declaring and traversing (x2) the prioritizing array on every execution of the anonymous function body.  See my answer for an optimized solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to someting like this....

```
$unsorted = Array(
        "0" =>"3470U11",
        "1" =>"3470E11",
        "2" =>"3470S13",
        "3" =>"3470G11",
        "4" =>"3470S12",
        "5" =>"3470S11",
        "6" =>"3470E12",
        "7" =>"3470U12",
        "8" =>"3470G13",
        "9" =>"3470G12",
        "10" => "s3470E13",
        "11" => "s3470U13"
    );

    $sortArr = array('G','D','S','U','E','T','A','L');

    foreach ($sortArr as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($unsorted as $key1 => $value1) {
            $val = substr($value1,-3,1);
            if ($val === $value) {
                $sortArrFin[] = $value1;
            }
        }
    }
    foreach ($sortArrFin as $key3 => $value3) {
        $val1 = substr($value3,-2);
        $newSortArr[] = $val1;
    }
    sort($newSortArr);
    $uniqueArr = array_unique($newSortArr);
    foreach ($uniqueArr as $key4 => $value4) {
        foreach ($sortArrFin as $key5 => $value5) {
            $val2 = substr($value5,-2);
            if ($val2 === $value4) {
                $Final[] = $value5;
            }
        }
    }
    foreach ($sortArr as $key6 => $value6) {
        foreach ($Final as $key7 => $value7) {
            $val3 = substr($value7,-3,1);
            if ($val3 === $value6) {
                $Last[] = $value7;
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($Last);
```

Comment: This unexplained snippet has way, way, way, waaaaay too many loops in it.  I would never do this in any code for any reason.  (...okay, maybe if I hated all of the other people on my dev team.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

1. your prioritizing array is an exhaustive list of potential letters and
2. you want to apply a secondary sorting rule which compares whole strings alphabetically and
3. you are running PHP7.4 or higher...

This is a concise, accurate, modern, professional way to implement the required sorting.  I am calling `usort()` which first sorts on the third-last letter based on the original index of the `$sortBy` array.  The "Elvis operator" (`?:`) separates the first rule from the second rule. The whole string comparision is the fallback sorting rule if the first rule results in a tie.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DHvQS))

```
$unsorted = [
    "3470U11",
    "3470E11",
    "3470S13",
    "3470G11",
    "3470S12",
    "3470S11",
    "3470E12",
    "3470U12",
    "3470G13",
    "3470G12",
    "3470E13",
    "3470U13"
];

$sortBy = ['G', 'D', 'S', 'U', 'E', 'T', 'A', 'L'];
$priority = array_flip($sortBy);

usort(
    $unsorted,
    fn($a, $b) =>
        ($priority[substr($a, -3, 1)] <=> $priority[substr($b, -3, 1)])
        ?: $a <=> $b
);

var_export ($unsorted);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '3470G11',
  1 => '3470G12',
  2 => '3470G13',
  3 => '3470S11',
  4 => '3470S12',
  5 => '3470S13',
  6 => '3470U11',
  7 => '3470U12',
  8 => '3470U13',
  9 => '3470E11',
  10 => '3470E12',
  11 => '3470E13',
)
```

Answer (score -1):

***try this : PHP usort() will the suitable for that***

```
<?php 
   $sortBy_Index = array_flip($sortBy);
   sort($data, SORT_STRING);
   $FlippedData = array_flip($data);
   $compare = function($a, $b) use (&$sortBy_Index, &$FlippedData) {
       $aid = substr($a, -3, 1);$bid = substr($b, -3, 1);
       $ai = $sortBy_Index[$aid];$bi = $sortBy_Index[$bid];

       if ($ai === null and $bi === null) {
          return $FlippedData[$aid] - $FlippedData[$bid];
       }
       if ($ai === null) { return 1; }
       if ($bi === null) { return -1; }

       return $ai - $bi;
  };
  usort($data, $compare);
  echo "<pre>";print_r($data);exit;
?>
```

***OUTPUT***

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3470G11
    [1] => 3470G12
    [2] => 3470G13
    [3] => 3470S11
    [4] => 3470S12
    [5] => 3470S13
    [6] => 3470U11
    [7] => 3470U12
    [8] => s3470U13
    [9] => 3470E11
    [10] => 3470E12
    [11] => s3470E13
)
```

Comment: See my answer for the professional/modern version of what this snippet attempts to do.

Comment: I am glad!!! that after almost 6 years you become professional and able to answer your own question :)

Comment: This is not my question. :) I  edited the question.

Answer (score -2):

try this instead

```
sort($unsorted);
$result=array();
foreach ($sortArr as $sortBy) {
foreach ($unsorted as $value) {
 if(strpos($value, $sortBy)!==false){
$result[]=$value;
}}}
print_r($result);
```