# How to compare two character in php?

Tags: php

Any one explain me how can I compare two characters in php

Here my Code:

```
$unsorted = Array(
        "0" =>"0000C11",
        "1" =>"0000A11",
        "2" =>"0000C13",
        "3" =>"0000D11",
    );

$sortArr = array('A','B','C','D');

foreach ($unsorted as $key => $value) {
        $val = substr($value,-3,1);
        foreach ($sortArr as $key1 => $value1) {
            if ($val === $value1 ) {
                $sortArrFin[] = $value;
            }
        }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($sortArrFin);
```

Here I want to check `condition` `if ($val === $value1 )` but it gives always true..
Means if `$val = C and $value1 = A` ti's return true...
Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You want to do the same as here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40816754/3933332 ?

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: I want to check how to compare two character.... Not sorting array....

Comment: if ($val === $value1 ) this my condition always true... if('A' == 'B'){...} it's return true... Why?

Comment: The logic of your code compares every item of the first array with every item of the second; you are getting all `$value`s because it's meant to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try following code, actually you have to make inner foreach to outer and outer for loop to inner.

```
    <?php
    $unsorted = Array(
            "0" =>"0000C11",
            "1" =>"0000E11",
            "2" =>"0000C13",
            "3" =>"0000D11",
            "4" =>"0000A11"
        );

    $sortArr = array('A','B','C','D','E');

    foreach ($sortArr as $key => $value) {
       foreach ($unsorted as $key1 => $value1) {    
            $val = substr($value1,-3,1);
            if ($val === $value ) {             
                $sortArrFin[] = $value1;                
            }
          }
    }

?>
```